# Getting an OR condition in regex for teleohone number

Tags: regex

I have a regex `^\+[0-9]?()[0-9](\s|\S)(\d[0-9]{9})$` which [works](https://www.regextester.com/115665) for below numbers.

It works for:

- +44 1213315000
- +4397973847797
- +1 2323214316
- +2923432432432

I want to include below numbers as well:

- 004397973847797
- 097973847797

I tried to use OR `|` as below :

`^((\+[0-9]?()[0-9])| ([0]{1,2}))(\s|\S)(\d[0-9]{9})$`

but I know I am messing it up.

can someone please help me here.

Comment: Is space required? You have a space before `([0]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: No,  I put the space but now I can see with space removed, it matches `097973847797` but not `004397973847797`

Comment: Try `^(?:\+[0-9]{1,2}|0{1,2}) ?\d{10,13}$`, see https://regex101.com/r/Bsdnln/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Many thanks. It works for the given pattern, i'll explore it from here. please put this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:\+[0-9]{1,2}|0{1,2}) ?\d{10,13}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bsdnln/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\+[0-9]{1,2}|0{1,2})`  - a non-capturing group: either `+` and one or two digits, or one or two `0` chars
- `?` - an optional space
- `\d{10,13}`  - ten to thirteen digits
- `$`  - end of string.

Comment: Thanks for explaining me. I just realized that it accepts `+097973847797` as well. I will check and modify your answer and will let you know

Comment: @Samuel If you do not want the match to start with `+09`, add the negative lookahead at the start: `^(?!\+09)(?:\+[0-9]{1,2}|0{1,2}) ?\d{10,13}$`